# Updates to hash aren't reflected in calls to HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI

Tags: perl, cgi

I've spent ~6 hours trying to figure this out.  I'm hoping a perl guru will help.

I have a program that loops, updating a hash with information about servers I'm polling. I'm using HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI to report this information to users.  I am running into an issue where the HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI module will not see updates to the hash and will only report data that the hash was initialized with.

I have the following code, abridged:

```
{
package LabBrowser;

use warnings;
use strict;
use Thread::Queue;
use LWP::Simple; 
use HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI;
use base qw(HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI);

my %problem_data_structure;


sub server_loop {
    while(1) {
        for my $server (@server_list) {
            fetch_server_info(@$server);
        }
    }
}

sub fetch_server_info {
    my ($hostname, $port) = @_; 
    my $content = fetch_webpage_content("http://" . $hostname . ":" . $port);   
    my @data = parse_data(content);
    $problem_data_structure{$hostname} = [@data];
}

##THIS SUB
sub handle_request {
    my ($self, $cgi) = @_;
    my $path = $cgi->path_info();

    ##THIS LINE 
    print Data::Dumper->Dump([\%problem_data_structure],['handle']);

}

}

my $pid = LabBrowser->new(8080)->background();
my $labBrowser = LabBrowser->init();
$labBrowser->server_loop();
print "$pid !!!\n";
```

I can get the data in %problem_data_structure anywhere in the program, except for handle_request. There, it seems as if it only knows about what the variable was initialized to. If I add some key, value pairs in the beginning, it will report that. However, it will not report anything added to the data structure since initialization.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: could you show us the code as to how you'r calling `handle_request`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `background()` is a clue that requests are being handled in a background process. Processes in Perl do not share memory, so when `%problem_data_structure` is modified in `handle_request`, the (original) copy of `%problem_data_structure` in the parent process is not affected.

Comment: Great Scott! That's it! I love you.  I didn't consider that there would be another process, even though the documentation does state that there would be. Bleh! Can I buy you a beer via paypal?